# Problems with Baking (three materials into one texture)

Tags: texture-baking

I am new to blender and I downloaded a model with three different materials shown on 'Textured' mode, I also tried this first on Blender Render and here's what I did.

The model is a pokemon, credits to ROEStudios.
[image]

Step 1: I imported the model //The Model is a wavefront file//

Step 2: I added the texture to it + I deleted the lamp and cube

Step 3: I split screened it and I went ahead and add a blank image with a size of 4096 * 4096

Step 4: I joined the model into one + I UV unwrapped (Smart UV Unwrapped)
[image]
Step 5:I selected the UV unwrapped model and the other one and hit bake, my choices are:

*Bake Mode: Texture

*Selected to Active

*Margin is 16px//Distance is 0.000//Bias is 0.001
And from there, the texture/material seems deformed and out of hand.

[image]
[image]
Is there more steps I might've missed, Thanks.
Model can be found here

http://roestudios.co.uk/project/3d-pokemon-models/136-flareon/

Comment: "And from there, things got crazy, My model looked all messed up." is not enough information to figure out what went wrong. Please post images of the bake result and what exactly you mean by "model looked all messed up"

Comment: @JtheNinja, Nevermind the 'Model itself', the problem, is the Texture/Material?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I just watched an online tutorial of baking. I forgot to add a little space for the objects before baking. **Margins